# Is there a way to loop on two variables when importing an Ansible role?

Tags: loops, variables, ansible

I'm importing an Ansible role in a play and running its 'install' task.The role is meant to create VMs on an hypervisor like Vbox and works fine. 
However, I want to use it to create several VMs at the same time, and I must provide 2 variables for this purpose :
- vm_ip : the ip of the vm to be created
- vm_name : the name of the vm to be created

I have already tried almost everything with loops, with_items and other things. For instance, this code doesn't work :

```
- name: Create VMs
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - import_role:
      name: vm_creation
      tasks_from: install
    vars:
      vm_ip: "{{ item.ips }}"
      vm_name: "{{ item.names }}"
      loop:
        - { ips: '192.168.20.4', names: 'test4' }
        - { ips: '192.168.20.5', names: 'test5' }
```

It is supposed to create both .20.4 and .20.5 VM's but the play crashes telling me this :"The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to have mis-indented the `loop` directive.  In doing so, you have defined a variable named `loop` rather than actually creating a loop (this is why `item` is undefined).

You will also need to use `include_role` rather than `import_role`. You can read about the difference between `include_role` and `import_role` in [the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_includes.html#includes-vs-imports).

```
- name: Create VMs
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - include_role:
      name: vm_creation
      tasks_from: install
    vars:
      vm_ip: "{{ item.ips }}"
      vm_name: "{{ item.names }}"
    loop:
      - { ips: '192.168.20.4', names: 'test4' }
      - { ips: '192.168.20.5', names: 'test5' }
```